# Textbox Telephone Number Format asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
@Html.TextBox("MyTextBox", "Value", new {style = "width:250px"})
```

I have textbox. I want to enter only phone numbers. The format is +1 (**_)** -___ Total 10 numbers (3+3+4)

How can I do it in `Html.Textbox` in asp.net mvc?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to do an input with a mask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578507/how-to-do-an-input-with-a-mask)

Comment: use masking for that.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way masked Html.Textbox, you can use jquery for this ([link](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin))
Or you can use **DataAnnotation** [*DisplayFormat*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10981049/displayformat-dataformatstring-for-a-phone-number-or-social-security-number) for this

Answer (score 0):

You can use a RegularExpression attribute in your Model like this:

```
public class MyModel
{
    // The regex maches this pattern: "+1 (xxx) xxx-xxxx" 
    [RegularExpression(@"^\+1 \(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{4}$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Phone Number.")]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in your View, you'll have:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PhoneNumber)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PhoneNumber)
```